# Ext.img and 404 not found

Tags: extjs, extjs4, image

Just a simple question but i search that since some hours : How catch 404 not found with Ext.img ?

I didn't find error event or something like that in docs, try some code but nothing work...

Have a nice day,

Thx.

Comment: Finaly i call php file to try img, that work and didn't too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't ever tried this but `Ext.Img` has a [loader](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-loader) config which accepts a `Ext.ComponentLoader`, so you could try this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Img',{
  //other config,
  loader : {
   url : 'src.jpeg',
   autoLoad : true,
   callback : function(img, success, response, opts)
   {
      if(!success)
      {
           //do whatever
      }
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, this didn't work i have a 404 reponse text so it's like success =(.

Comment: you can read the response and check the status from there.. `response.status` i think

Comment: Right, thx ! =) But i stay on ajax and php function cause this method didn't write some red row in firebug =p